# Converting String to PublicKey

Tags: java, android, security, public-key-encryption

I am passing a public key as a string from a web server to an android device where the key is converted back from a string to a public key. On the android device I am getting this error

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0c0000af:ASN.1 encoding routines:OPENSSL_internal:TOO_LONG
```

The android class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   /*
    * Other code
    */
   PublicKey publicKey = KeyUtil.StringToPublicKey(publicKeyString);
}
```

Key class:

```
Public class KeyUtil {

public static byte[] publicKeyToByteArray(PublicKey key) {
    return Base64.encode(key.getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT);
}

public static PublicKey byteArrayToPublicKey(byte [] array) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(array, Base64.DEFAULT));
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return kf.generatePublic(spec); //Error is thrown here
}

public static PublicKey StringToPublicKey(String array) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    byte[] b = Base64.encode(array.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    return byteArrayToPublicKey(b);
}
}
```

This error only happens on the android device, I am able to convert the code to and from string to PublicKey with no problems in java.

I can't figure out how to convert a string to publicKey on the android device with out getting an error. Help is greatly appropriated.

Comment: Have you compared the encoded public keys in Java and Android? Are there differences?